# Intersection preserves homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $Z$ be a topological space with subspaces $X$, $Y$, $X'$ and $Y'$.
Suppose that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $X'$ and $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y'$ do we have that 
$X\cap Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $X'\cap Y'$? thanks for your help!

Comment: Absolutely not. This will be false for virtually any example you think of.

Comment: Well, $X$ is a subspace of $X$ always, but do you really mean that? Because if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ then $X\cap Y=Y$.

Comment: I think the first $X$ was supposed to be a different letter.

Comment: Yes i edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no reason for this to be true. Take everything to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $Y = Y'$ to both be the $x$-axis (this is to make the example as easy to visualize as possible). Now take $X$ to be a circle intersecting the $x$-axis at two points and $X'$ to be a circle tangent to the $x$-axis. (Of course by deforming the circle we can arrange for even more intersection points.)